# Read memory address content

Tags: c

I need to know how to read the contents of a memory address (0x046C) and save it into a unsigned long variable (this address has the number of ticks since the system booted up), I´m not sure which function use (scanf?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be undefined behavior and is implementation-defined (how to convert integer to pointer), but it **may be** archived by this:

```
unsigned long data = *((unsigned long*)0x046C);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned long * ptr = (unsigned long *)0x046C;
unsigned long value = *ptr;
```